# Flask Migrate: Alembic converting choices into 255

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I'm using sqlalchemy_utils to add a "choices" field to my database. And after I ran my migrate using Flask Migrate, it converts all my choices into 255, below is a simplified example:

```
# models.py
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice import ChoiceType

class Stuff(db.Model):
    type = db.Column(ChoiceType(Stuff_types))
```

After running `manage.py migrate`, the migration file looks like:

```
# /migrations/versions/1234migrate.py
import sqlalchemy_utils

def upgrade():
    sa.Column('type', sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice.ChoiceType(length=255), nullable=False),
```

I manually changed those `length=255` into the correct types(in this case `stuff_types`), and it worked. I wonder if I did not set up alemic correctly to work with sqlalchemy_utils. Or if there is a better solution that I'm not aware of?

Thanks guys!

Comment: What do you mean by "correct types"? Why shouldn't the length be 255?

Comment: @dirn for example, tuples of choices like ('stuff1', 'Stuff One'), ('stuff2', 'Stuff Two)

Comment: All of those will fit into a 255 character field. What is the exact problem you were running into? Did you get an error running the migration? Did you get an error inserting into the field?

Comment: @dirn yes there was error, because this field is suppose to be a `ChoiceField`, not a `StringField`, and the `length=255` argument is for `StringField`.

Comment: Databases don't always have a field that can handle choices (e.g., enums). SQLAlchemy will store the value in a string-based field. Unless you are getting an exception due to Alembic's use of `StringField`, your model should work as you expect it to.

Comment: @dirn Unfortunately that is not the case, and when I manually change the `length=255` back to the choices tuples, the migration's upgrade was successfully executed.

Comment: [It looks like sqlalchemy-util's custom types aren't supported by Alembic](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/129).

Comment: @dirn yeah that's my guess. Maybe I'll just write up some scripts to clean up this mess for future references... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I dont get this fully with Alembic. What worked for me is going into the created migration file in alembic > versions and editing it.

In my case I has a array of TYPES and I added that to the upgrade function, since Alembic didn't seem to do it. I them replaced the length=255 with 'TYPES' and it was all good